# How to downconvert NB-IoT signal using GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I have captured an NB-IoT signal to a file (I-Q samples) using GNU Radio. The signal is centered at 768.2 MHZ and has a bandwidth of 200KHz. I need to downconvert the frequency to 767.8 MHz also using GNU Radio. How can I do this?

[image: GNURadio signal capture to file]

[image: NB-IoT signal spectrum]

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Your question is sadly self-contradictory: If you've captured an RF signal as I/Q, then it's *already* downconverted!

Comment: So, whatever you've recorded is *no longer* centered around 768.2 MHz. (You'd need > 1.5 GHz sampling rate for that, or 2 times > 768 MHz, which is very high. To downconvert and then sample a bandwidth of 200 kHz, you only need > 2× 200 kHz. That's why your hardware gives you IQ samples: it's easier and contains the same information as the RF passband signal). **You'll have to explain in detail how you acquired this signal, and why you think it needs more downconversion.**

Comment: So, when you save the signal as IQ samples it means that the signal is no longer centered around 768 MHz? What I need to do is to create 2 NB-IoT signals to transmit. So if I capture one, then I downconvert it and then add it to the original I'll have 2 signals that I can transmit, am I right?

Comment: "Capturing" already encompasses downconversion. So, there's nothing you need to do. You must, however, really read up on what "complex equivalent baseband" is, otherwise you'll have not much understanding of what your Pluto SDR does, nor how NB-IoT works. It's not really clear to me why you think you need another round of downconversion!

Comment: Ok, I guess I wasn't very clear with my problem because I'm new to SDR. What I need to do is transmit 2 NB-IoT Signals using one Pluto SDR. One needs to be centered at 767.8 MHz and the other one has to be centered at 768.2 MHz. Is this possible? Thats why I captured a signal to a file and I thought that if I changed its frequency and then added them together (the original plus the downconverted one) I could get both signals to transmit. But now I see its not that simple or maybe its not even possible.

Comment: yes, that's possible, signal-wise. But: NB-IoT basically uses an LTE protocol stack on top, not quite sure you can simply replay things that you've recorded; channel spacing is multiples of 15 kHz, so 200 kHz is not a valid spacing; either of your frequencies *has* to be incompatible to the standard.